# Fetch <td> text while using WWW::Mechanize to fetch <a> within that <td> tag

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

I'm new to Perl-HTML things. I'm trying to fetch both the texts and links from a HTML table.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<td>Td-Text
    <br>
    <a href="Link-I-Want" title="title-I-Want">A-Text</a>
</td>
```

I've figured out that **[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/)** is the easiest module to fetch things I need from the `<a>` part, but I'm not sure how to get the text from `<td>`. I want the two tasks happen back-to-back because I need to pair each cell's `<td>-Text` with its corresponding `<a>-Text` in a hash array.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) is good at extracting links, but if you need to get other text, I usually combine it with [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder).  Something like this:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($mech->content);

foreach my $td ($tree->look_down(_tag => 'td')) {

  # If there's no <a> in this <td>, then skip it:
  my $a = $td->look_down(_tag => 'a') or next;

  my $tdText = $td->as_text;
  my $aText  = $a->as_text;

  printf("td-text: %s\n a-text: %s\nhref: %s\ntitle: %s\n",
         $tdText, $aText, $a->attr('href'), $a->attr('title'));
}
```

The only problem with this code is that you don't want all of the text in the `<td>` tag.  How you fix that is up to you.  If the `$aText` is sufficiently unique, you might do something like:

```
$tdText =~ s/\Q$aText\E.*//s;
```

In the worst case, you'd have to write your own function to extract the text elements you want, stopping at the `<br>` (or however you determine the stopping point).

Comment: In addition to that, I can recommend http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder-LibXML/ which is an extension of HTML-TreeBuilder that also gives the programmer all the power of XPath and LibXML. I've been using it a lot for testing HTML pages recently.

Answer (score 0):

I found that HTML::TreeBuilder is a great way of parsing HTML documents and pulling info out of them.  In this case, something like:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $page = get($URL);
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($page);

foreach my $cell ($tree->look_down(_tag => "td")) {
   my $links = $cell->extract_links();
   foreach my $link (@$links) {
      print "href: ", $link->attr("href"), "; text: ", $link->as_text, "\n";
   }
}
$tree = $tree->delete;
```

**Resources**

- [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder)
- [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Element)

Comment: Ummm ... `extract_links` does not work the way you seem to think it does.  The return value is an arrrayref of arrayrefs, not an arrayref of elements.